# iOS app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-apps

I want to integrate facebook with my iOS app because I want to promote my app in facebook. I want to create an ad campaign on facebook to get more users for my iOS app. I have created my facebook app as it is said in the guide but facebook doesn't approve my app, if I disable Facebook login it says that "Mobile apps built for iOS and Android must use Facebook Login."
So I enable facebook login and facebook says that "Your iOS app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration. Please either implement Facebook Login or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app."

I don't know what to do and I'm very upset.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ I am assuming you haven't implemented facebook login with their SDK in iOS?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the facebook login with their SDK.